# Clean url with rewrite rule does not work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I read some tutorials about getting clean urls. I tried some of the codes they gave in the tutorials but I can't get a simple example to run...

I would like to change: `http://domain.com/brigandze/mannen/index.php?p=0`
To: `http://domain.com/brigandze/mannen/0/`

I used this code and put it in the directory `domain.com/brigandze/mannen/`

I have this code in my htaccesfile:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?p=$1    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either set your RewriteBase correctly or use the full path in your RewriteRule (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for RewriteBase documentation).

```
RewriteBase /brigandze/mannen/

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^brigandze/mannen/([0-9]+)/?$ brigandze/mannen/index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem is that the web server looks at URLs starting from the DocumentRoot unless you tell it otherwise.  In your case, that means that your rule is trying to rewrite

```
http://domain.com/0/
```

By adding the `RewriteBase`, it will look at the correct place.

Comment: That won't work because OP writes he puts the htaccess into the "/brigandze/mannen/" directory. DocRoot will therefore be "/". ;)

Comment: Where do I need to change this? Like so: brigandze/mannen/index.php?p=$1    [NC,L] ?

Comment: As you've beaten me by a few secs anyway, I'll give you a [+1] for the edit (and correct answer) and kill my own (now obsolete) answer. Fair is fair. Cheers!

Comment: After these recent edits this answer looks identical to my answer :)

Comment: :D and thanks for making me think harder about how `mod_rewrite` works!

Comment: @anubhava:  except that mine was there 7min earlier  :)

Comment: It was there but it was wrong and you corrected it after I posted mine.

Comment: I corrected it a few times to fix formatting, add documentation, and to change the \d+ to match the [0-9]+ that was used in the original question, but the correct answer with RewriteBase was there earlier...take a look at the edit history/times if you want to

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Very strange... My host is one.com.

Comment: What is not working?  The URL will still appear the same, but behind the scenes the PHP _GET variable "p" should be set to the number.

Comment: Ah then you have a misunderstanding of what mod_rewrite does.  You don't type `index.php?p=0` into the browser.  Instead, type `brigandze/mannen/0` into the browser.  That will stay the same, but it will be processed as `index.php?p=0`

Comment: I had this misunderstanding indeed. Thanks a lot for your help and patience. My question is fully answered!